# Android LocationManager getting integer value of coordinate (whereas of double)

Tags: java, android, location, listener, locationmanager

I have an issue using the Location Api. I'm trying to get the Location from any of the provider available, using this code:

```
//Définir ma localisation
final LocationManager manag = (LocationManager) ActivityRechercheConcession.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
//Choix du service de localisation en fonction de critères
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setCostAllowed(false);
crit.setAccuracy(1000); //précis à au moins 1km pret
final String choix_source = manag.getBestProvider(crit, true);
//demander la position courante
manag.requestLocationUpdates(choix_source, 10000, 0, new LocationListener(){
    //Lors de la capture de la position
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("LocationListener","New position from "+choix_source+": ("+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude()+")");
    }
}
```

But when I'm sending coordinate with the Emulator Control (like long: 7.745304, lat : 48.589326)
I'm only getting the integer part in my Location data (like long 7.0, lat 48.0)
So calculation method on those value are totally false.

Why do I lose the fractional part of those data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from Eclipse's Emulator Control and not from the code.

Some to resolve it I have to rightly configure the eclipse.ini by adding this line:

```
-Duser.language=en
```

corresponding to my locale so I used :

```
-Duser.language=fr
```

and afterwards I had to use "coma" instead of "dot" in value I sended.
That way the code is running well :D

Answer (score 1):

The `Criteria.setAccuracy` method takes only two flags: `ACCURACY_FINE` and `ACCURACY_COARSE`, not absolute numeric value you have used. I guess `1000` is interpreted as coarse accuracy here and hence you get trimmed coordinates.

In other words, you should use:

```
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
```

to obtain precise coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but even with that change the results given is the same =(